# MSDB is growing due to our sending database mail with attachments. Can I update MSDB system table 'attachment = NULL'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mail

`sysmail_attachments` is growing and using a lot of space for backups. I don't want to keep what's in the attachment, just the record of the mail, including recipients and attachments. 
I am considering running the below on our live system but don't know what effect it will have:

```
update dbo.sysmail_attachments
set attachment = null
```

Has anybody done this before? Can anyone think of potential problems?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new logging table to store counts, then create a SQL Agent job that runs the aggregations of how many emails you sent, insert that to your logging table, then run `sysmail_delete_mailitems_sp` to clean up to msdb table. If your only need is to keep track of how many emails went out, this would be the safer option.

In fact, you might be able to get all the info you need from the Database Mail logs instead of the Database Mail tables. Get your counts from `sysmail_log` and then you can purge `sysmail_mailitems`. Double check this on a dev box.

Comment: Thanks. We do, however, need to keep a record of mail recipients and times, so a full log but without attachments.

Comment: @cloudsafe Have you checked if `sysmail_log` has what you need?

Comment: That is just showing the service starting/stopping and errors. We don't have a DEV server with DBMail so can only apply the changes on Live.